# Calling Oracle procedure with PL/SQL record Type from Spring JDBC

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to call Oracle procedure with one IN parameter which has PL/SQL Record type.

I wrote a following code:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("P_INSERTCLIENT");
jdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("V_CLIENT_RECORD", OracleTypes.ARRAY));

MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("V_CLIENT_RECORD", client);

jdbcCall.execute(in);
```

When I execute the code I get a following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: com.my.test.resource.model.Client@5df613a2
```

I wonder is it possible to call a procedure with IN parameter defined as PL/SQL Record and how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Oracle JDBC driver doesn't provide access to the PL/SQL `RECORD` type, neither for `IN` nor for `OUT` parameters.

#### Workaround for a single procedure call:

But you can work around this limitation by using an anonymous PL/SQL block in JDBC (or Spring JDBC) directly:

```sql
DECLARE
  rec MY_PACKAGE.MY_RECORD;
BEGIN

  -- Replace these by your actual record attributes:
  rec.first_name := ?;
  rec.last_name := ?;
  ...

  p_insertclient(rec);
END;
```

This works perfectly fine for a single procedure call.

#### Solid solution for many of these calls:

If you do the above quite frequently, it's worth generating stubs that produce the anonymous PL/SQL strings automatically, rather than writing those manually all the time. You can automatically discover all the PL/SQL `RECORD` types in your schema with the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  x.TYPE_OWNER, x.TYPE_NAME, x.TYPE_SUBNAME, a.ARGUMENT_NAME ATTR_NAME,
  a.SEQUENCE ATTR_NO, a.TYPE_OWNER ATTR_TYPE_OWNER,
  nvl2(a.TYPE_SUBNAME, a.TYPE_NAME, NULL) package_name,
  COALESCE(a.TYPE_SUBNAME, a.TYPE_NAME, a.DATA_TYPE) ATTR_TYPE_NAME,
  a.DATA_LENGTH LENGTH, a.DATA_PRECISION PRECISION, a.DATA_SCALE SCALE
FROM SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS a
JOIN (
  SELECT
    a.TYPE_OWNER, a.TYPE_NAME, a.TYPE_SUBNAME,
    MIN(a.OWNER) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) OWNER,
    MIN(a.PACKAGE_NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) PACKAGE_NAME,
    MIN(a.SUBPROGRAM_ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) SUBPROGRAM_ID,
    MIN(a.SEQUENCE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) SEQUENCE,
    MIN(next_sibling) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) next_sibling,
    MIN(a.DATA_LEVEL) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY a.OWNER ASC, a.PACKAGE_NAME ASC, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC) DATA_LEVEL
  FROM (
    SELECT
      lead(a.SEQUENCE, 1, a.SEQUENCE) OVER (
        PARTITION BY a.OWNER, a.PACKAGE_NAME, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID, a.DATA_LEVEL
        ORDER BY a.SEQUENCE ASC
      ) next_sibling,
      a.TYPE_OWNER, a.TYPE_NAME, a.TYPE_SUBNAME, a.OWNER, a.PACKAGE_NAME, 
      a.SUBPROGRAM_ID, a.SEQUENCE, a.DATA_LEVEL, a.DATA_TYPE
    FROM SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS a
    WHERE a.OWNER IN ('MY_SCHEMA')     -- Possibly replace schema here
    ) a
  WHERE (a.TYPE_OWNER IN ('MY_SCHEMA') -- Possibly replace schema here
  AND a.OWNER         IN ('MY_SCHEMA') -- Possibly replace schema here
  AND a.DATA_TYPE      = 'PL/SQL RECORD')
  GROUP BY a.TYPE_OWNER, a.TYPE_NAME, a.TYPE_SUBNAME
  ) x
ON ((a.OWNER, a.PACKAGE_NAME, a.SUBPROGRAM_ID) = ((x.OWNER, x.PACKAGE_NAME, x.SUBPROGRAM_ID))
AND a.SEQUENCE BETWEEN x.SEQUENCE AND next_sibling
AND a.DATA_LEVEL = (x.DATA_LEVEL + 1))
ORDER BY x.TYPE_OWNER ASC, x.TYPE_NAME ASC, x.TYPE_SUBNAME ASC, a.SEQUENCE ASC
```

[See more details about this technique in this blog post (from which the query was taken)](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/11/08/use-jooq-to-read-write-oracle-plsql-record-types/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use OracleTypes.Array since it's a record.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28928

**PL/SQL TABLE, BOOLEAN, and RECORD Types**

It is not feasible for Oracle JDBC drivers to support calling arguments or return values of the PL/SQL RECORD, BOOLEAN, or table with non-scalar element types. However, Oracle JDBC drivers support PL/SQL index-by table of scalar element types.

See Also:

"Accessing PL/SQL Index-by Tables"

As a workaround to PL/SQL RECORD, BOOLEAN, or non-scalar table types, create container procedures that handle the data as types supported by JDBC. For example, to wrap a stored procedure that uses PL/SQL boolean, create a stored procedure that takes a character or number from JDBC and passes it to the original procedure as BOOLEAN or, for an output parameter, accepts a BOOLEAN argument from the original procedure and passes it as a CHAR or NUMBER to JDBC. Similarly, to wrap a stored procedure that uses PL/SQL records, create a stored procedure that handles a record in its individual components, such as CHAR and NUMBER, or in a structured object type. To wrap a stored procedure that uses PL/SQL tables, break the data into components or perhaps use Oracle collection types.