# How to call a procedure in Oracle from clojure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, clojure

I want to be able to call a procedure in an Oracle database using Clojure.

I have a connection to an Oracle database and I can query the tables of the db using select queries with parameters.
E.g.: If I run "SELECT * FROM user_tables" I get the list of tables as the result. So the connection is working and I do have the correct credentials to make this connection.

I'm using the following dependencies:

```
[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.7.11"]
```

and as oracle driver I tried these

```
[oracle.jdbc/oracledriver "11.2.0.2"] (ojdbc6 driver I installed locally under this name)
[oracle.jdbc/ojdbc7 "12.1.0.2"]
[com.oracle/ojdbc8 "19.3.0.0"] or [oracle.jdbc/ojdbc8 "12.2.0.1"]
```

My java version is:

```
java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09) 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)
```

Using the ojdbc6 driver results in:

```
Execution error (SQLException) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer/processError (T4CTTIoer.java:440).
ORA-29481: Implicit results cannot be returned to client.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2785
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 2779
ORA-06512: at "<My procedure name>", line 157
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Using the version 7 or 8 result in:

```
#:next.jdbc{:update-count -1}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this in such a way that I can see the same result set as in SQL-Developer?

Clojure code used to make the connection:

```
(defstate ^:dynamic *oracle*
  "This variable has the database connection to the Oracle Database"
  :start
    (if-let [jdbc-url (:oracle (env :database-url))]
        (conman/connect! {:jdbc-url jdbc-url})
        (do
             (log/warn "database connection URL was not found, please set :database-url for oracle in your config, e.g: dev-config.edn")
             *oracle*))
  :stop
    (conman/disconnect! *oracle*))

(conman/bind-connection *oracle* "sql/queries-oracle.sql")
```

In resources/sql there is the file queries-oracle.sql which contains the procedure to be called. I tried several ways to call it:

```
EXEC schema_name.procedure_name :param1, :param2, :param3;
EXEC schema_name.procedure_name(:param1, :param2, :param3);
BEGIN EXEC schema_name.procedure_name :param1, :param2, :param3; END;
BEGIN schema_name.procedure_name :param1, :param2, :param3; END;
```

All these have a :name through which they are called. Which I'm now trying from a REPL.
The result of these tries is:

1. Invalid SQL-Statement
2. Invalid SQL-Statement
3. Encountered the symbol "schema_name" when expecting one of the follwing:...
4. #:next.jdbc{:update-count -1}

Comment: You'll have to show at least the *signature* of the procedure and you Clojure code calling it.

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774006/calling-oracle-procedure-with-pl-sql-record-type-from-spring-jdbc